# Strange outline around image in Safari

Tags: html, css, image, safari

Can someone explain where the outline is coming from around this image? When I view it on my iPhone, or on my laptop in Safari 6.1.4, I see a grey outline on the left and bottom sides of the image.

In Chrome or Firefox, I don't see this outline.  What is causing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/flyingL123/s4pfhmkp/1/

Here's the code:

```
<img src="http://s10.postimg.org/sd8qp5bol/facebook.jpg"
     width="30"
     alt="Share on Facebook" />
```

Additionally, the outlines disappear if I zoom in on my iPhone or browser.

Comment: On safari 7.0.6 it looks ok

Comment: I see it on the bottom of the image on my iPad, but if I zoom in it disappears. I suspect it may be a rendering issue with the browser.

Comment: Yea, same with me, it disappears if I zoom in as well. I should have included that in the question. Is it just something about the image that's causing the issue?

Comment: Still not sure what the problem was but using a different image seems to have fixed it.